# PHP search/filter array with given conditions, recursively

Tags: php, arrays, search, recursion, filter

I am getting data from an api (that I cannot query agains, just get lump of data), and then I need to query against those data like I would do using database. Only It would be great if I could do it recursively.

**Data example**

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [url] => https://domain.com/api/1.0/item/1/            
        [name] => some_item
        [category] => some category
        [created_by] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [screen_name] => tomino
            )
        [current_user_domain_access] => Array
            (
                [is_active] => 1
                [is_administrator] => 1
            )
        [alerts_enabled] => 0
    )
```

(much shortened version)

I receive an array of objects like that and then I need to select/filter/search by values.

**Something like this**

```
SomeModel::find(['category'=>'some category','current_user_domain_access' => ['is_administrator' => 1]]);
```

Is that something that would be possible in PHP? I was thinking about flattening the array, but then there might be key conflicts

Comment: So what actually you need to do over here flatten your array or your query

Comment: @Uchiha how can I flatten my query?

Comment: what you mean by flatten your query please elaborate

Comment: @Uchiha I dont know, you said I should flatten query

Comment: As always, stackoverflow very helpful...

Comment: What's your expectation over here. Can you please define that what is your expected output from that given array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) select data : You can select data by (array_name->id),(array_name->url) and so on...

2)Filter : add conditions according to requirement

3)search :  in_array(),array_search

Comment: Accepting just in the sake of so I dont have to come back here